# Angular forEach returning first letter instead of whole word

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple angular function to Get the category property from a JSON object and return each unique value. However when I go to ng-repeat through these values, I only get the first letter instead of the word. I'm sure this is just some small misunderstanding on java-script on my part but any help would be awesome. In addition to my pasted work below please reference my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/xZvPoZ)

Angular JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

.controller('starWarsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {"name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
     "index":88,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Yoda",
     "index":69,
      "cat":"jedi"},
    {"name": "Lando",
     "index":31,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Han Solo",
     "index":90,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Darth Vader",
     "index":98,
      "cat": "sith"},
    {"name": "Jar-Jar Binks",
     "index":80,
      "cat": "alien"},
    {"name": "Mace Windu",
     "index":45,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Chewy",
     "index":76,
      "cat": "smuggler"}
  ];

  $scope.getCategories = function() {
    var categories = [];

     angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item) {
      angular.forEach(item.cat, function(category) {
        if (categories.indexOf(category) == -1) {
          categories.push(category);
        }
      })
    });
    return categories;
  }

})
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="starWarsCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li class="box" data-ng-repeat="cat in getCategories()">
          <h2>{{cat}}</h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: because you are iterating on the word. `forEach(item.cat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second forEach loop is working on a string. This second loop not even needed.

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item) {
    //item.cat is a string
    if (categories.indexOf(item.cat) == -1) {
      categories.push(item.cat);
    }
});
```

Your first `forEach` loop visits each item in `scope.data`. These items are JS objects. I'm not too familiar with Angular and the loops available, but generally you can't loop arrays the same as objects. However, you don't need to loop through the object since your just checking the `cat` property. So you can just work with the object at that point.